# Intersect outputs shapefile with null values

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, intersect, null-geometry

I have a model that iterates through a folder of field boundaries (polygons) and produces an intersect against a shapefile of points. The output is then a point shapefile for each boundary. Note: There are not points in every field boundary. My goal is to get an output of points ONLY if the points ALSO are in a field boundary. It works, except I get a set of points that have empty values for field boundaries that do not have point in them. How can I eliminate these empty point features?
    [image]
    [image]

[image]

Comment: Can you explain how creating a temporary feature layer from each iterated shapefile prior to the intersect would work? I don't see the logic in this. Also, the spatial join still produced the same result as far as I could tell.

Comment: There could be something wrong with the geometries. Try repair geometry for each input or convert all shapefiles to features in a file geodatabase.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get an output of points ONLY if the points ALSO are in a field boundary. You can use **(Select by location)** instead of Intersect tool

Your ModelBuilder will be somethink like this (I change it depends on a sample data)

[image]

If Points will be the selected feature, polygons are the input feature (Then use WITHIN)

If Polygons will be the selected feature, points are the input feature (Then use COMPLETELY CONTAIN)

[image]

Result: Polygons contain points

[image]